# Error in the example code of A Tour of C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm going through Mr. Stroustrup's "A Tour of C++" book. In section 9.3 String Views, the author gives the following example:

```cpp
string cat(string_view sv1, string_view sv2)
{
    string res(sv1.length()+sv2.length());
    char *p = &res[0];
    for (char c : sv1) // one way to copy
        *p++ = c;
    copy(sv2.begin(),sv2.end(),p); // another way
    return res;
}
```

When I try to compile this function, I get following error as `std::string` class doesn't provide any constructor which takes a single int parameter.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(std::basic_string_view<char>::size_type)'   11 |     string res(sv1.length()+sv2.length());
```

I checked the [Errata for 2nd printing of A Tour of C++](https://www.stroustrup.com/Tour_printing2.html) but there is no mention of this issue.

Is this a bug in the example provide or else I'm missing something else?

Comment: There's not a single constructor taking only an integral value as parameter, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string it should be `std::string res{sv1.length()+sv2.length(), '\0'};` but preferrably you'd use `std::string res; res.reserve(sv1.length()+sv2.length()); res.append(sv1); res.append(sv2);` to avoid the unnecessary initialization with 0 chars at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a bug in the example provide or else I'm missing something else?

Yes this is an **erratum** in the book as `std::string` doesn't have a constructor that has only one parameter of type `int`(or convertible to int).

Instead it has a constructor `std::string::string(size_type, char)` that can take a `char` as the second argument. In particular, from [`std::string`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/):

> ```
> fill (6)  string (size_t n, char c);
> ```
>
> (6) **fill constructor**:
> Fills the string with `n` consecutive copies of character `c`.

---

Thus to resolve the erratum, we should pass a second argument as shown below:

```
string res(sv1.length()+sv2.length(), '\0');
```